# Как определить message_id у сообщения, присланного боту в беседе?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как определить message_ids у присланного сообщения? Например, если я хочу использовать метод удаления сообщений в вк messages.delete?
Как это передать в функцию типа

```
***vk_session.method('messages.messages.delete', {'conversation_message_ids': ??, 'peer_id': peer_id, 'delete_for_all': 1})***
```

Answer (score 1):

В событии message_new у персланого сообщения есть reply_message в котором хранится параметр conversation_message_id, который вам и требуется.

```
{
    "type": "message_new",
    "object": {
        "message": {
            ...............
            "reply_message": {
                "date": 1645097526,
                "from_id": -19823079,
                "text": "Бла-бла-бла",
                "attachments": [],
                "conversation_message_id": 31,
                "id": 797,
                "peer_id": 2472076945
            },
        },
        ...............
    },
    "group_id": 19823079,
    "event_id": "bd4d35253b7de7312344f42371551f7d129b8999a89",
    "secret": "sawqe0891io2109hjln32"
}
```

Далее для удаления к примеру сообщения, в методе **messages.delete** передайте параметр cmids (cmids - сокращение от conversation_message_id).

И еще меня смущает ваша запись

> vk_session.method('**messages**.**messages**.delete')

у вас дважды повторяется messages, когда должно быть messages.delete. Итоговый результат должен быть следующим

```
vk_session.method('messages.delete', {'cmids': conversation_message_ids, 'delete_for_all': 1})
```